# Can you stop people from using your app on an iPad 1?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I know that you can limit apps based on iOS version, but is there a way to limit them based on the device? For some reason, my app locks on an iPad 1, but works fine on iPad 2. I intend to fix this, but otherwise it's ready for release and I would like to release it now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it to work on iPhones and iPods, or *only* the iPad 2?

Comment: Just the iPad 2. Due to the size, it doesn't work on anything smaller.

Comment: I am quite sure, that u have to fix it.

Comment: U should fix this bug... although you can technically limit the devices that you can support, you're restricting your potential clients for no reason. That said, you can add a requirement in your info.plist file to require iPad + camera camera hardware, which will do what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Require iPad 2 or iPhone 4S in App Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919586/how-to-require-ipad-2-or-iphone-4s-in-app-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the Info.plist key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to restrict the app to devices that support your hardware requirements. In particular, you can limit your app to running only on devices that have a camera. That will rule out the original iPad.

See [the Info.plist docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) for all of the things you can require.

Of course, the best solution you already know -- to fix the bugs.

Comment: I am not sure, if this complies with the app store submission rules, if the app does not use the camera at all.

Comment: It may or may not, but the OP didn't say anything about the app store ;)