# How to limit iOS app in store to 4S and iPad 3 only

Tags: ios, app-store

My iOS app is CPU hungry. It runs well on iPhone 4S and even better on new iPad. But on iPhone 4 it provides bad user experience and I want somehow disable anything under 4S to download my app from app store. I already forced amrv7 requirement but this means anyone with 3GS and over can install it. I would like to have enforced requirement of dual core Cortex A9 as I use two threads to get speed I need.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3 does not seem to list thing I want. Closest one is `bluetooth-le`, which I believe exists only on newer devices. Any better ideas?

Comment: If you try to use things like bluetooth to restrict your app's device list without actually using bluetooth features, you'll probably get rejected.

Comment: This is what I also think. And actually they are right, this is ugly hack.

Comment: Seems I made duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919586/how-to-require-ipad-2-or-iphone-4s-in-app-store?rq=1 
Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple seems to be discouraging apps that are so CPU hungry that they don't run on devices below the top end that are still being sold.  Thus listing bluetooth or the front camera, if your app doesn't need them, will likely get the app rejected.

Best bet might be to either improve your app's performance, or to edit your app's description with the requirements for decent performance prominently listed, and eat the bad ratings and reviews from customers who can't read.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if there's a way to exclude iPhone 4 while including 4S, but you can configure your app to only run on iPhone 4 and later and iPad 2 and later by requiring `front-facing-camera` in your Info.plist.

Of course, a change like this can only be made to a new app, since Apple prohibits restricting the hardware requirements for an app already in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to restrict on the new iOS version that is not supported on older devices.
Still this won't work for all the devices. While uploading your app yust write a note that
it is a demanding app. and should be used on new devices only