# How to exclude first generation iPad from my AIR for iOS game's compatibility?

Tags: ios, ipad, air, compatibility

I've built an iPad game using Flash, exporting with AIR 3.4 for iOS and the game runs fine on iPad 2 and iPad 3, but runs slow and cannot be played on iPad 1. However, I couldn't find where to exclude iPad 1 from compatibility list. Where can I disable compatibility for iPad 1 at Flash?

Thanks,
Can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Apple doesn't like when you do this, you could make a front-facing camera a requirement for the app even though it might not technically use it. (See: [How to Require iPad 2 or iPhone 4S in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919586/how-to-require-ipad-2-or-iphone-4s-in-app-store?rq=1))

Another option would be to make the app target iOS 6 only but this might limit your adoption.

Comment: Ok, I'll be trying that if there is no other option, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but it looks like you can eliminate iPad 1 by setting the minimum OS to iOS6

<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
   <string>6.0</string>

Here is a link: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1094168